# Send event when module was executed

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom-events

I'm really stuck on this.. I need to send an event when both **Load module** and **Hide module** code was executed, and only then send the event. Ideas on how to achieve this?

**// Load module**

```
(
    function() {
        var s=document.createElement('script');
        s.type='text/javascript';
        s.async=true;
        s.src='https://example.com/bundles.js';
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    }
)();
```

**// Hide module**

```
var inverval = setInterval(hideClass, 100);

function hideClass () {
    if ($(".class").hide().length > 0) clearInterval(inverval);
}
```

**// When both happend = Send a event to Google Analytics**

```
DigitalData.push({'event':Module, 'eventLabel':'Page'});
```

Comment: @clijsters do you have any more input?

Comment: I think @Ikechi Michael's input is quite what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your only option, then perhaps there's something you are going about wrongly. Anyway, let's see ... Only when both events have taken place.

```
var HandleTwoEvents = function (key1, key2) {
   this.count = 0;
   this.pack = [];
   $self = this;
   this.startListening = function(fn) {
      fn = fn || function () {}
      window.addEventListener(key1, function (ev) {
         if ($self.pack.indexOf(key1) < 0) {
            $self.pack.push(key1);
            $self.count++;
            if ($self.count == 2) { 
                fn(); 
                $self.count = 0;
            }
         } 
         console.log(key1, ev);
      });
      window.addEventListener(key2, function (ev) {
         if ($self.pack.indexOf(key2) < 0) {
            $self.pack.push(key2);
            $self.count++;
            if ($self.count == 2) { 
                fn(); 
                $self.count = 0;
            }
         }
         console.log(key2, ev);
      });
    }
}
```

Forgive me, i always use this function to create events

```
function createEvent(name, obj) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
    evt.initEvent(name, true, true);
    evt.data = obj;
    dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Now, to log both events ...

```
var both = new HandleTwoEvents("EventKeyOne", "EventKeyTwo");
both.startListening(function () {console.log("This means that both Events have taken place")});
```

Now, let's test ...

```
createEvent("EventKeyOne", {}); 
//key, data are the arguments ... function defined in startListening above does not execute, and upon inspection, both.count is seen to be 1
createEvent("EventKeyTwo", {});
//Now, function executes. 
//It also works if "EventKeyTwo" is raised before "EventKeyOne"
```

Happy Coding!

PS: I'm sure there's a better way to handle the use of the $self variable, with some function binding, i guess. I've never been able to learn it.